# Invalid character '&#x0' encountered

Tags: java, xml, blackberry, java-me

I am getting following exception while parsing the xml.

```
Fatal error at line -1  Invalid character '&#x0' encountered. No stack trace
```

I have Xml data in string format and I am parsing it using DOM parser.
I am parsing data which is a response from Java server to a Blackberry client.
I also tried parsing with SAX parser,but problem is not resolved.
Please help.

Comment: <START><TAG1>value</TAG1><TAG2>value</TAG2><TAG3>value</TAG3><TAG4>value</TAG4></START>

XML is in String format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution,

I just trimmed it with trim()
and it worked perfectly fine with me.

Comment: Yes, maybe that's 'cause the "null" char was at the end of your String. But I think that the real solucion should be using Replace of the char "\0", and change it for an empty-string.

Answer (score 16):

You have a null  character in your character stream, i.e. char(0) which is not valid in an XML-document.  If this is not present in the original string, then it is most likely a character decoding issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your code currently calls `getBytes()` using the platform default encoding - that's very rarely a good idea. Find out what the encoding of the data really is, and use that. (It's likely to be UTF-8.)

If the Blackberry includes `DocumentBuilder.parse(InputSource)`, that would be preferable:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData);
try {
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xml); 
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

If that doesn't work, have a *very* close look at your string, e.g. like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < xmlData.length(); i++) {
    // Use whatever logging you have on the Blackberry
    System.out.println((int) xmlData.charAt(i));
}
```

It's possible that the problem is reading the response from the server - if you're reading it badly, you could have Unicode nulls (\u0000) in your string, which may not appear obviously in log/debug output, but would cause the error you've shown.

EDIT: I've just seen that you're getting the base64 data in the first place - so why convert it to a string and then back to bytes? Just decode the base64 to a byte array and then use that as the basis of your `ByteArrayInputStream`. Then you never have to deal with a text encoding in the first place.

Comment: Also,how do I check that I have \u0000 in the string?
I am new to xml handling,Is there any way to chk.?
Please help.

Comment: Look at the second code snippet - it shows how to examine the string manually. You can use xmlData.indexOf("\u0000") to check programmatically.

Comment: Which solution? And have you examined the string? It would help if you'd give a lot more details in the question.

Comment: Hi Jon, I tried the code snippet above using StringReader.
I also tested by without converting xmlDAta from byte[] to string.
Im still getting same error.

Comment: So it sounds like you've got bad data. If you could post the base64 for the smallest response you can generate, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream xml = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes());
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xml);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
xml.close();
```

Above is the code I am using for parsing.